# What is the Rindler wedge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

Consider relativistically accelerating  body along the coordinate
$$x = \frac{c^2}{\alpha} \cosh\left(\frac{\alpha}{c} \tau\right) -\frac{c^2}{\alpha}$$
Why there is such "special" distance as $$d=\frac{c^2}{\alpha}$$
Anything happens at point of $x=d$? I see in Wikipedia it is called also the Rindler Horizon distance.

Is there any significannce of such time $$T=\frac{c}{\alpha}$$
What is the [Rindler wedge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates) and are these values related to it?

Comment: $c^2/\alpha$ is subtracted to make $x=0$ at $t=0$.

Comment: It is clear- the question is not on $x=0$, but on $d=c^2/\alpha$. I meant the spit horizon in a Rindler wedge occurs at distance $d=c^2/\alpha$. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

The significance of the distance $d$ for the uniformly accelerated observer (with initial $x=0$ at $t=0$) is that $\textit{his Rindler horizon}$ is located at distance $$d=\frac{c^2}{\alpha}$$ in the direction opposite to his acceleration (behind him). When he approaches x=d he won't be able to receive any information from the point of his origin. It will happen at the time when $\cosh\left(\frac{\alpha}{c} \tau\right)=2$ or $$\tau=\frac{c}{\alpha} acosh(2)$$